# Getting the group match from two data frames keeping the row order in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have these datasets:

```
data_a <- data.frame(label = c("A","B","C","D"))
data_b <- data.frame(lobel = c("C","D","B","A"),
                     parsu = c("TR","TR","TD","TD"))
```

And I want `data_a` to match the group `parsu` keeping the row order of `data_a` so the expected result is:

```
label   parsu
A       TD
B       TD
C       TR
D       TR
```

What I have tried is:

```
data_a %>% left_join(data_b, by = c("label","lobel"))
```

But I get this error message:

```
Error: Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `lobel`.
```

Please, could you help me with this question? What is the reason that I can't join those two data frames?

Comment: Yes base R is always preferable in my opinion and it is much faster. Thank you very much. Regarding your question there are some very good examples in the documentations of `left_join` for `by` argument for matching many columns whose names don't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data.frame(label=data_b$lobel[match(data_a$label,data_b$lobel)],parsu=data_b$parsu[match(data_a$label,data_b$lobel)])
```

This gives the desired data frame by reordering data_b via the match() function. Another way would be:

```
colnames(data_b)[1] <- "label"
data_b[match(data_a$label,data_b$label),]
```

Comment: thank you, just a question, why dplyr doesn't work? My intended answer was in tidyverse (that's why I put dplyr in the tags)

Comment: Oh there's probably a way to do it in some package like dplyr, I just try to use base R when possible, especially when the answer is straightforward like this

Comment: Thank you very much @Baroque, this is a different way to solve the problem I had. It made me investigate more about `match`

Answer (score 4):

In order for your code to work you just have to put `=` between the column names you would like to match. Normally when the column names don't match we put an equal sign between the pair of names that are supposed to match.

```
library(dplyr)

data_a %>%
  left_join(data_b, by = c("label" = "lobel"))

  label parsu
1     A    TD
2     B    TD
3     C    TR
4     D    TR
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help! Just a missing `=` generated me a doubt about my code!

Comment: My pleasure. These things happen for me every day! Just normal.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `merge` from `base R`

```
merge(data_a, data_b, all.x = TRUE, by.x = 'label', by.y = 'lobel')
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun!, it seems that I can merge like left, right and inner join with that function!

Comment: @Alexis.  Yes, you just need to use `all.x` or `all.y` as TRUE for left/right  and `all=TRUE` for full_join.  By default it gives output of inner join